# How can I send information from a python file to a html file?

Tags: post, request, get, python-datetime

I want to send a date (from a calendar in the html file) to a js and a python file. I could save the date in the js file but not in app.py. It looks like the variable fecha_inicio is empty, maybe it's a problem with request.json, but I don't know what is it. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/prueba2.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>Prueba2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prueba 2</h1>
    <br>


    <!--PRUEBA CALENDARIO-->
    <h2>Calendario 4</h2>
    <br>
    <p>Min: 01-01-1997 y max: 31-12-2030</p>
    <input type="date" name="begin" id="meeting-time"
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value=""
        min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31">

    <button onclick="miFuncion()">Haz clic</button>

    
    <br><br>
    <h3>{{ fecha_inicio_objeto }}</h3>

<script src="/static/js/prueba2.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// código a ejecutar cuando se hace clic en el botón
function miFuncion() {
    var fechaInicio = document.getElementById("meeting-time").value;
    //var fechaFin = document.getElementById("fechaFin").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/", true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({fechaInicio: fechaInicio}));
    console.log("se enviaron los datos");
    console.log("fecha de inicio")
    console.log(fechaInicio);//aaaa-mm-dd
  }
```

---

PYTHON

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from datetime import datetime, date
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"]) 

def procesar_datos():
    #fecha_inicio = datetime.date(request.json['fechaInicio'])
    #fecha_inicio = request.json['fechaInicio']
    #fecha_inicio = str(date.today())
    #fecha_inicio = str(request.json['fechaInicio'])
    #fecha_inicio = request.json()
    fecha_inicio = request.json('fechaInicio')
    fecha_inicio_objeto = datetime.strptime(fecha_inicio, '%Y-%m-%d') #%Y-%m-%d
    
    return render_template('prueba2.html', 
                          fecha_inicio_objeto = fecha_inicio_objeto) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I tried changing the GET method to the POST method but it didn't work. What can I do?